# How to get the full stack trace printed on an Exception?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an unhandled Exception in my Android project and in Logcat it ends with:

```
at kotlinx.serialization.json.Json.decodeFromString(Json.kt:97)
at io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.KotlinxSerializationConverter.deserialize(KotlinxSerializationConverter.kt:82)
... 35 more  <------- why isn't that shown?
```

Note the `... 35 more` at the end. Does that mean 35 lines more or what's the unit of the 35? How to get the full stack trace printed to logcat?

Comment: Is there a "Caused by" attached to that exception, with a stack trace of its own?

Comment: 35 more means there are 35 more entries on the ball stack that are suppressed. As very call stack entry is usually printed in one line it is equivalent to 35 lines that ha been suppressed. That a stack trace is truncated at the "wring position" (from the developer's perspective) is nothing unusual in Java. You can try to set a preak point in the exception handler and then check the exception in the debugger at run time to see the full stack trace.